# If we have $0\leq A \leq B$ for matrices $A$ and $B$, must $A$ and $B$ commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-algebras

$0\leq A \leq B$ means that $A$ and $B-A$ are positive as operators, i.e. $0\leq \langle Ax, x\rangle \leq \langle Bx, x\rangle$ for all $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample: $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&2}$ and $B=\pmatrix{3&1\\ 1&3}$.